# d3 tree <g> tag padding/border overall styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, styling

So I've built a tree that will collapse/expand with animations using d3's library. I'm still very new to d3 and I'm not sure how to add my specific styling to the fray. Any suggestions on how to style `<g>` tags?

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

And here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 120,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 120
            },
            width = $(window).width() - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = $(window).height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width])

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        buildJson(function (data) {
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            root = data;
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            function collapse(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }

            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);

            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

            function update(source) {

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Compute the new tree layout.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.y = d.depth * 350;
                });

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Update the nodes…
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function(d) {
                        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on("click", click);

                nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

                nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? -12 : 12;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Transition nodes to their new position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

                nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 4.5)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

                nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    })
                    .remove();

                nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6);

                nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Update the links…
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) {
                        return d.target.id;
                    });

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        var o = {
                            x: source.x0,
                            y: source.y0
                        };
                        return diagonal({
                            source: o,
                            target: o
                        });
                    });

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Transition links to their new position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        var o = {
                            x: source.x,
                            y: source.y
                        };
                        return diagonal({
                            source: o,
                            target: o
                        });
                    })
                    .remove();

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Stash the old positions for transition.
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                });

                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                // Remove Root Node, ultra mega important!!!
                // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                node.each(function(d){
                    if (d.name == "flare") 
                        d3.select(this).remove();});
                link.each(function(d){
                    if (d.source.name == "flare") 
                        d3.select(this).remove();});
            }

            // Toggle children on click.
            function click(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                }
                else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                // If the node has a parent, then collapse its child nodes
                // except for this clicked node.
                if (d.parent) {
                    d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
                        if (d !== element) {
                            collapse(element);
                        }
                    });
                }
                update(d);
            }

            function collapse(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }

        });

        // Get Data and format it properly for presentation
       function getJsonData (pathToData, callback) {
            $.getJSON( pathToData, function() {
                console.log( "Retrieving: " + pathToData );
            }).done(function(data) {
                callback({
                    error: false,
                    data: data
                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                callback({
                    error: true
                });
            });
        }

        function buildJson (builder) {
            var runOnce = true, categories_raw, technologies_raw, formatted_json = {
                'name' : 'flare', 
                'children' : []
            }

            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            // First get all of the categories and subcategories
            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            getJsonData('assets/json/categories.json', function (data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    // Categories and Subcategories Retreived now build it out
                    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    categories_raw = data.data

                    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    // Technologies retreived now build it out
                    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    getJsonData('assets/json/technologies.json', function (data) {
                        if (!data.error) {
                            technologies_raw = data.data

                            var categories = categories_raw[0], subcategories = categories_raw[1], technologies = technologies_raw, formatted_categories = [], formatted_subcategories = [], formatted_technologies = []

                            subcategories.forEach ( function (value, index) {
                                formatted_subcategories.push({
                                    'name' : value.label,
                                    'id' : value.id,
                                    'children' : [],
                                    'parent' : value.parent
                                })
                            })

                            technologies.forEach ( function (value, index) {
                                var result = formatted_subcategories.filter(function( obj ) {
                                    return obj.id == value.subCat;
                                });

                                if (typeof result[0] != 'undefined') {
                                    result[0].children.push({
                                        'name' : value.label
                                    })
                                }
                            })

                            categories.forEach ( function (value, index) {
                                var result = formatted_subcategories.filter(function( obj ) {
                                    return obj.parent == value.id;
                                });

                                formatted_json.children.push({
                                    'name' : value.label,
                                    'id' : value.id,
                                    'children' : result
                                })
                            })

                            builder(formatted_json)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What does your data look like ? So i can create a fiddle ..

Comment: Here is a gist of some json that could work https://gist.github.com/Quixomatic/4cc96a44bca4fb81ce963ceaada89569

Comment: you are using two sets of data : categories,json and technologies.json ...

Comment: https://preview.c9users.io/quixomatic/rainking-fun-view/assets/json/

Comment: that contains all 3 files

Comment: sort a fiddle out for us, im too busy to create one myself. I can help you out if you do

Comment: I think I can manage on my own really just needed advice on styling, but I'm getting more comfortable with it as I go. A little annoying that someone downvoted it because its a reasonable question.

Comment: If you have any interest in my progress check out: https://preview.c9users.io/quixomatic/rainking-fun-view/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well even though this was downvoted I still think it is important that an answer exists.

https://gist.github.com/Quixomatic/f39d338bb4b4790d38f7d08b52f34b98

This link points to a gist that shows my solution to the problem. Thanks for the help, no one.

[image]